# component lightning static resource js call another js resource

Tags: static-resources, component

i have a component lightning and i import 2 scripts "PDF.js" and "scripts.js" my static resource have 3 files zip "PDF.js", "script.js" and "worker.js"

```html
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.pdf + '/pdf.js'}"/>
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.pdf + '/script.js'}"/>

    <input id="inputFile" type="file" onchange="convertToBase64();" />    

    <div id="data"></div>   
</aura:component>
```

in my script.js static resource i call my worker.js

```js
pdfjsLib.workerSrc = 'worker.js';
```

but i have a error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pdfjsLib is not defined throws at https://componentstudy-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1579614876000/olianiTrailhead__pdf/script.js:1:1 ReferenceError: pdfjsLib is not defined
    at script.js:1
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to choose a different library. Aside from possible timing issues regarding the load order for scripts, you cannot use Workers of any type in Lightning because of the [Locker API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer).

Comment: I understand your point but this lib is not for generating PDF but reading and generating readable text from a PDF

Comment: @Guilherme The other half of my answer is still a concern, then... Locker API won't let you have a service worker.

Comment: @Guilherme Did you check the Developer Console for errors? I'm pretty sure you should see something about an unsupported API or some such in the logs.

Comment: on my developer console, I have no error, but only on the browser console

Comment: about the locker service, I had this problem, but solved it by downgrade the component version and now i have this error i post